Question about PIC16F18345 Evaluation Board
I am trying to understand the schematic of MPLAB® XPRESS PIC16F18345 EVALUATION BOARD.
However, I cannot understand the following parts.

Why there are 2 microcontrollers (PIC16F18 and PIC16F14) on this board? When we connect the USB cable, which of these microcontrollers do we load the programm to?
Where does the 20-pin integrated circuit, called the PIC programming adapter in the schematic, appear in the real-life picture of this board?
What is the name of the component labelled TH1 in the schematic?
There is a symbol above the text DISCONNECT POWER, what is the symbol?
In the schematic, there is a symbol on the cable connected to the 11th and 12th pins of the MCU named PIC16F1454, what is the name of this symbol? What is it used to explain?
And finally, what is the purpose of the circuit to which the PIC16F1454 mcu is connected, why these structures are placed around this MCU?

I am trying to analyse an MCU circuit for the first time, I don't know where to start. Thank you in advance for your help.

This image is taken from page 27 of the document Microchip MPLAB® Xpress Evaluation Board.

The picture is taken from this link.

1: Why there are 2 microcontrollers (PIC16F18 and PIC16F14) on this board. When we connect the USB cable, which of these microcontrollers do we load the programme to.
The PIC16F14 is just a programming interface to download the code into the target MCU using a PC and USB connection.
2: Where does the 20-pin integrated circuit, called the PIC programming adapter in the schematic, appear in the real-life picture of this board?
They are the solder connections at the boarder of the PCB, labeled with white printing.
3: What is the name of the component labelled TH1 in the schematic?
This is a polyfuse, self resetting if the problem has disappeard.
4: There is a symbol above the text DISCONNECT POWER, What is the symbol?
There are two supply options, 5.0 V or 3.3 V. You chose between them with a solder drop across the pad pairs marked with a white circle on the PCB. Do never connect both options -> danger to come.
5: In the schematic, there is a symbol on the cable connected to the 11th and 12th pins of the mcu named PIC16F1454, what is the name of this symbol? What is it used to explain?
It indicates, that the two traces must be implemented impedance controlled on the PCB. High speed differential signals like USB lines D+ and D- need this to work properly.
6: And finally, what is the purpose of the circuit to which the PIC16F1454 mcu is connected, why these structures are placed around this MCU.
They provide signal conditioning for the programming interface of the target MCU, RESET, DATA and CLOCK.


The 16F18345 is the one you're programming. The 16F14 just serves as a USB interface.
The 20 pin programming adapter in the diagram are the 20 castellated pads on the PCB.
Looks like a PPTC resettable fuse
Those are jumper pads. They can be bridged with a solder blob to make a connection. In this case used to select either 3.3V or 5V. Only one is supposed to be bridged at a time.
Only a guess but it might be to indicate those traces are a impedance controlled differential pair, as they are the USB data lines.
TGDAT,TGCLK and TGMCLR are the data, clock and reset line that allow the USB interface PIC to upload a program to the 16F18345.

